# Conditional read-only permissions on a picture library?

Tags: picture-library

In a SharePoint Server 2010 site, there are two roles: Admins and normal Users.

There is a image library with some items (well, about 50.000 items).

An admin can view the list of all items and add, edit, aprove, deny and delete all items. Since here any problem.

A normal user can:

- add an item
- list all aproved items, and his own items (aproved or not)
- edit his own items
- delete his own items
- Not aprove or deny an item.

How can I allow an user to edit an item if it's created from him, and "read-only" if is created by another user?

Comment: If you need more information, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Picture libraries do not allow for item level permissions like lists which is unfortunate as you'd think the same should hold true in both places.  One option would be to use a workflow tool, like SPD Activities, Nintex, K2, or your own developed action to handle setting item level permissions.  With a library of that size, that will cause some performance issues.

I think the only route in this case would be to use an event receiver to evaluate who the current user is and if they're the item creator or an admin.  If so, allow them to edit the item, if not don't allow them to do so.