# Timer job fails while trying to data

Tags: development, custom-timer-job

I'm fetching data from a excel file and creating sharepoint groups for each entry. There are around 10000 entries for which i need to create sharepoint groups

I created a SharePoint custom timer job to execute the task but it fails.  Is this possible to do with a timer job?

Comment: You need to add more information about your problem, what kind of data?, ?where do you need the data be stored?

Comment: I'm fetching data from a excel file and creating sharepoint groups for each entry. There are around 10000 entries for which i need to create sharepoint groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the job definitions and schedule you will see that the server is busy managing 100s of jobs an hour.  These are meant to run pretty quick.  When doing large sets of workloads, its typically a better idea to use the timer job for the scheduling and management of the work, but move the work somewhere else.  It might be better to perhaps wrap that code in a web service and then have the timer job call the web service.

Answer (score 0):

You have limitation for item level permissions.

check this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/sharepoint-2010-performance-with-item-level-permissions-limit) , I think it can help you.